# R Shiny - value of input as a variable

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I want to use value selected in input (below) in loop.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  #User dropbox
  selectInput("state", "Choose state", choices=ListaKampani$Nazwa)
  #Print table to UI
  ,tableOutput("table1")
ID_kamp <- reactive({input$state})

for (i in ID_kamp) {print(i)}
```

How I can use value from input as a variable in code?

In next attempt i tried this code:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("wyb", "Wybierz", c(1,2,3))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
wybor <- reactive(input$wyb)  
  
for (a in 1:wybor()) {print(a)}
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But i have error:
Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.).

How I can make variable for loop make reactive? Reactive() function is not enough ?

Comment: Reactives are functions, so you have to use `ID_kamp()`. However, this works only in a reactive context (and your `for` loop is not in a reactive context). Please read a tutorial about shiny, e.g.: https://www.mastering-shiny.org

Comment: You can't use reactive elements in the `ui`, you need to use it in your server function. Do you have a server functions?